# How to get a reference of a VC in a function defined in another file

Tags: ios, swift

Say I have a bunch of helper functions defined in **helper.swift**, one of them is `func1`.

`func1` will be called in VC1 and VC2, how to get the reference of the VC where `func1` is called in the body of `func1`?

I know setting VC as a parameter of `func1` or making `func1` as an extension of `UIViewController` works, but I want an answer just as I describe.

Answer (score 0):

Put the VC1 reference in the parameters list

```
func1(controller: UIViewController) {
    // use controller to do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this. But this seems like a workaround. I want to see if there is a way to reference without set it as a parameter